# Find values of $a$ if $f$ is a one-one function

Tags: calculus

> If $$f(x) = x^3 + (a+2)x^2 + 5ax + 5$$ is a one-one function then find the set of values of $a$.

I know that I need to find values of $a$ for which function is strictly monotonic increasing or strictly monotonic decreasing and we check monotonicity of function by its derivative $f'(x)$.

here $$f'(x) = 3x^2 + 2x(a+2) + 5a$$

so, what condition should I impose on $f'(x)$ to make the given funtion one one or strictly monotonic?

Comment: You need only pick $a $ so that $f'(x)$ does not have two zeros. Use its discriminant.

Comment: Note: It's OK if $f'$ has only one zero. Then $f$ will still be strictly increasing or strictly decreaing, even though it is flat at a single point. [By strictly increasing is meant if $a<b$ then $f(a)<f(b).$ Similar for strictly decreasing.]

Comment: @coffeemath this is what i thought. Now, f is parabola, then it can be one one only if x takes positive real values. So, is it okay to take domain (0,infinity)?

Comment: No, look at formula for $f$ -- it's cubic so $f$ will not be a parabola. Its *derivative* will be. And if that derivative doesn't cross the axis twice, then the original $f$ will be 1-1 for *all* values of $x$ [i.e.domain all reals]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT.** You know that $f'(x)$ is a parabola. To make $f(x)$ always increasing, you want $f'(x)>0$; that is, you want the parabola to always be above the $x$-axis. It touches the $x$-axis when it only has one root. What formula can you use to see what makes this only have one root in terms of $a$? Would this then give you a condition on $a$ to force the parabola to be always above the $x$-axis?

Comment: Thanks for this simple explanation. Since, f is a parabola, so is there also any condition on x? I think domain of f should be positive real numbers, since f is one one.

Comment: @Mathsaddict there's no restriction on f taking *any* real number. The way I interpreted f being "one-to-one" is f is a bijection from R to itself.

Answer (score 1):

A differentiable function is strictly monotonic when its derivative is not $0$ on any segment, meaning if $f'(x)=0$ then there is a small $z>0$ with the property that for any $0<y<z :f'(x+y)\neq 0,f'(x-y)\neq 0$, and if $\forall x:f'(x)\geq 0$ or $\forall x:f'(x)\leq 0$.

Try and use that. You are on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $y=ax^2+bx+c,$ where $a>0.$ Now $$y=a(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a})=a\big((x+\frac{b}{2a})^2+\frac{c}{a}-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\big)=a\big((x+\frac{b}{2a})^2+\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a^2}\big).$$ So if you have $4ac-b^2\geq0$ then $y$ will be non-negative for all $x.$

Try to connect these ideas to your problem.

Comment: if 4ac - b^2 = 0, then y will be zero at -b/2a. There should be no problem if f' has only one root. Why do i need 4ac - b^2 to be greater then 0? I think it can also be 0 at one point.

Comment: @Mathsaddict I agree with your comment here. [see my second comment on your question]t

Comment: @coffeemath I agree with yall. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\lim_\limits{x\to -\infty} f(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_\limits{x\to +\infty} f(x)=+\infty$. That is why you need to make sure the function $f(x)$ is strictly increasing $\left(x_1<x_2 \Rightarrow f(x_1)<f(x_2)\right)$. It implies:
$$f'(x)\ge 0 \Rightarrow 3x^2 + 2x(a+2) + 5a\ge 0 \Rightarrow D\le 0 \Rightarrow (a+2)^2-15a\le0 \Rightarrow \\
\frac12 \left(11 - \sqrt{105}\right)\le a\le\frac12 \left(11 + \sqrt{105}\right).$$
See [WA animation](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xyf0aiqijd) for $f'(x)$.

Also note that $f'(x)=0$ when $a=\frac12 \left(11 - \sqrt{105}\right) \ \left(\text{or} \ a=\frac12 \left(11 + \sqrt{105}\right) \right)$ and $x = \frac{\sqrt{35/3}}{2} - \frac52 \ \left(\text{or} \ x = -\frac52 - \frac{\sqrt{35/3}}{2}\right)$, which implies it is an inflection point (which is still one-to-one).
See [WA animation](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ub8q848cj8) for $f(x)$.

Comment: Why D cannot be equal to 0?

Comment: Thank you for asking critical question. Please, see the updated answer.